# Need to remove duplicates from a list. Set() function isn't working. Neither is a for loop method

Tags: python, excel, duplicates, set, xlrd

I am scraping data from an excel sheet using xlrd. The data I want is in two columns (columns with "IDs" and "locations"). Each column contains thousands of entries, most of which are exact duplicates. I am simply trying to create 2 lists that contain all the unique entries from both excel columns. This is most of my code, and showing an example of what it returns when I print one of the lists:

```
rawIDs = data.col_slice(colx=0,
                 start_rowx=0,
                 end_rowx=None) #getting all of column 1 in a list
IDs = []

for ID in rawIDs:
    if ID not in IDs:
        IDs.append(ID) #trying to create new list without duplicates, but it fails

rawlocations = data.col_slice(colx=1,
                     start_rowx=0,
                     end_rowx=None) #getting all of column 2 in a list

locations = []

for location in rawlocations:
    if location not in locations:
        locations.append(location) #same as before, also fails

print set(IDs) #even set() doesn't remove duplicates, it just prints "rawIDs"
```

No matter what I seem to do, it always prints the original list, with all the duplicates remaining.

Goes without saying but, I have already looked at a lot of other similar stackoverflow posts and their solutions don't work for me.

edit: I was wrong about a particular. I realized that printing

```
print set(IDs)
```

actually returns

"set([item, item, item...])" as the output. So it basically puts "set()" around the "rawIDs" output. This doesn't make sense to me either though...

Also here is an example screenshot:

[image: here is an example screenshot]

Comment: I don't see how `set` couldn't work. You need to provide a [mcve] to support your claim...

Comment: Sorry, I added a screenshot, does that make it clear?

Comment: What is the return type of `col_slice`? Probably they are considered distinct by `set()` even when all values are the same, you should extract the `text` parts as strings first and then put it into a set.

Comment: A screenshot is not reproducible, we can't do anything with it... my guess is that you have different objects with identical 'representation' values, that is they have a different hash code (due to other different fields) although the one info used to print them appears to be the same. (Just like there are many different "John Smith", which seem to be the same person only if you look only at their name)

Comment: I think you guys must be right although I still have not figured it out, I am looking into it. I don't see what else it could possibly be. Thanks!

Comment: But now since I am a noob I don't know how to make them not distinct. I will look into it.

Comment: You can use `type(ID)` to see what kind of object it is, and then search the docs of xlrd for it. With `dir(ID)` you can see the methods and fields of it.

Comment: @mwil.me - You were on the right track when you asked what the return type of `col_slice` is. It returns a list of Cell objects. `col_values` is the proper way to get a list of the values.

Answer (score 1):

THE SOLUTION:

It seems that metadata (like maybe the coordinate position in the table) was being stored so each item in the lists was actually distinct due to this metadata even though the text might be the same.

Modifying the for loops so they add the *strings* of the items, rather than the items themselves, solved my problem and yielded new lists with no duplicates.

```
rawIDs = data.col_slice(colx=0,
                     start_rowx=5000,
                     end_rowx=5050)

IDs = []

for ID in rawIDs:
    if str(ID) not in IDs:
        IDs.append(str(ID))

rawlocations = data.col_slice(colx=1,
                     start_rowx=0,
                     end_rowx=None)

locations = []

for location in rawlocations:
    if str(location) not in locations:
        locations.append(str(location))

print IDs #it prints a list with no duplicates!
```

Comment: It's not "metadata". `col_slice` returns Cell objects. Unless custom comparison methods are defined (which they aren't here), objects are compared by memory address. You should be using `col_values` instead, and don't bother with converting everything to strings.